# Firebase delete from storage method throws object not found error

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete files from my firebase storage but I keep getting this error

> FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'products_img/test_8xtx7e9wkf_FOODBANK_(1).png' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}

on this code

```
  public delete() {
      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product')) return;
      this._productService.delete(this.id);
      this.product.images.forEach(d => {
          this.uploadform.deleteFileStorage(d.name);
      });
      this._router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }
```

but it deletes without errors if I do this

```
  public delete() {
      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product')) return;
      this._productService.delete(this.id);
      this.uploadform.deleteFileStorage(this.product.images[0].name);
      this._router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }
```

this is the method in the service for file delete

```
  public deleteFileStorage(file) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${file.name}`).delete();
  }
```

If you want to help but need a to see the whole source code, leave a comment and I would share it with you.

Comment: Sounds like the first item in the array deletes fine, but there may be something else in the array you're not expecting. Try logging each path you try to delete in `deleteFileStorage` and see if you get any nonsense paths that don't actually exist in your storage bucket.

Comment: @Jeff, the error had to do with the urls tnk you.